# O "use strict" ainda é útil com os novos recursos trazidos no EcmaScript 6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

O EcmaScript 6 traz os recursos `let` e `const`, que evitam que variáveis sejam redeclaradas e sobrescritas sem querer, além de limitar o escopo das variáveis criadas.

A questão é: com essas mudanças dessa nova versão ainda é útil utilizar a diretiva `use strict` no início dos scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ainda é útil porque o *strict mode* não está relacionado apenas com declaração de variáveis, como `let` e `const`, mas também a outras situações onde o JavaScript *sem strict mode* nenhuma exceção é disparada, embora haja falha ou pode ser um erro de digitação, como por exemplo, duplicar parâmetros de uma função:

```
function f(a,b,a){}
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Duplicate parameter name not allowed in this context
```

Outras utilidades do `stric mode` você pode conferir **[nesta documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)**.